# How to click the inner image in a framelayout with multiple imageviews

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this an xml with a framelayout with a multiple imageviews.  My purpose is to click each image when they are visible but I keep on clicking the outermost image.  They have transparent part so that they will be place on their right position. Please help

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/base_rack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/storemap" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mrack1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/rack1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mrack2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/rack2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mrack3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/rack3" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mrack4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/rack4" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mrack5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/rack5" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mrack6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/rack6" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mrack7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/rack7" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mrack8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/rack8" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mrack9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/rack9" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mrack10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/rack10" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mrack11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/rack11" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mrack12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/rack12" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mrack13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/rack13" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mrack14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/rack14" />
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change this to be a FrameLayout with the background as the store image and then containing a RelativeLayout with the images for the rack one below the other using the layout above/below of the RelativeLayout

Comment: i'm sorry but i didn't work it's the outermost image that's been clicked :(

Comment: this is my scenario for example rack12 and rack3 is the one visible so i need to click both image but when i'm clicking rack3 it's still rack12 that's been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the images clickable, a good choice would be to use ImageButtons rather then an ImageView. Then use the advice of Anand and make the layout that contains the ImageButtons have a background image. Another option would be to make the back ImageView.setClickable(false); . I hope this helps